# Stop Mongo Db from creating backups

Tags: mongodb

Can any one tell me how to stop mongo DB from creating backup restores ?
If my DB name is "Database"

It is creating backups like
DataBase1
Database2
Database3
.
.
.
DataBase.ns

I want to use only working copy

Comment: These are not backups but datafiles + database namespace file. This is how the storage engine saves your data to disk

Comment: Hello Orid,
Thanks for your reply, My issue is my DB size has gone to 30 GB including all "datafiles" and database namespace file. Because of this read and write operations are becoming slow. Could you please suggest me a way by which I can increase the response speed of mongo Db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB allocates data files like this:

First, a namespace file (`mydb.ns`) and a data file with 64MB (`mydb.0`). If the required space grows larger, it will add a 128MB file (`mydb.1`) and continuing like this, doubling the file size every time until the files are 2GB each (`mydb.5` and following).

This is a somewhat aggressive allocation pattern. If you perform a lot of in-place updates and deletes, your datafiles can fragment severely. Running the [**repair database** command](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/repairDatabase/#dbcmd.repairDatabase) via `db.runCommand({repairDatabase:1})` can help, but it requires even more disk space while it runs and it stalls writes to the DB. Make sure to **carefully read the documentation first**.

Before you do that, run [`db.stats()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/dbStats/), then compare `dataSize` (the amount of data you actually stored), `storageSize` (the allocated size including padding, but w/o indexes), and `fileSize` (the disk space allocated). If the differences are huge (factors of > 3), repair will probably reclaim quite a bit of disk space. If not, it can't help you because it can't magically shrink your data.